# Why meridian time zones are not uniform?

Tags: latitude-longitude, time

Looking at this image:

[image]

Why are time zones are not uniform? (I mean not really parallel !!).

For example, time zone -11 and -10 are pretty overlapping near Alaska and time zone 0 changes the form to grab Island and so on ....

Comment: Timezones are an artifact of civilization. The fact that they follow, for the most part, level 0 and level 1 administrative boundaries is a demonstration of this. Unfortunately, this geographic trivia isn't GIS-centric enough on it's own to be a good fit with our Focused GIS Question database.  Please take the [Tour] to better understand our purpose here.

Comment: "artefact of civilisation" is a useful turn of phrase! I was in need of such a term when explaining why [GPD contains some things and not others](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/39508/if-someone-goes-for-a-haircut-does-it-increase-gdp/39530#comment60276_39530) recently. I am curious if you came up with it yourself and if not, where you first heard/saw it used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone):

"Time zones tend to follow the boundaries of countries and their subdivisions because it is convenient for areas in close commercial or other communication to keep the same time."

Comment: I thought it must follow a strict geographic rules... but for social and commercial reasons, it's ok !